# split strings from a column in separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am trying to split string values from a column, in as many columns as strings are in each row.
I am creating a new dataframe with three columns and I have the string values in the third column, I want to split in new columns (which already have headers) but the numbers of strings which are separated by semicolon, is different in each row
If I use this code:

```
df['string']= df['string'].str.split(';', expand=True)
```

then I will have left only one value in the column while the rest of the string values will not be split but eliminated.

Cal u advice on how this line of code should be modified in order to have the right output?
many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output? Your description is too vague. e.g. Do your strings always split into the same number of tokens? If not, how many should be retained? Why is the sample code not as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the original column, you can take the result of split and join with original DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_string':['car;war;bus','school;college']})
df = df.join(df['my_string'].str.split(';',expand=True))
print(df)
        my_string       0        1     2
0     car;war;bus     car      war   bus
1  school;college  school  college  None
```

Answer (score 0):

Then we do

```
df['string']= df['string'].str.split(';', expand=True).str[0]
```